# Pictures are stored but not displayed in Camera Roll

Tags: ios, photos, camera, sqlite, space

Well, I've been running low space for a long time and this led to a sudden disappearing of old photos (actually 5000 of them - the oldest ones) in camera roll. I don't know how how that worked - maybe iOS tried to free up some space by removing the thumbnails (without asking me???).

The main advice is to remove the **photos.sqlite** and other similar files from **PhotoData** directory. That did nothing - the restored base is lacking my OLD ones. Still you can find them all in DCIM folder.

How can I add them back to sqlite??? Thanks a lot!!

upd. ios 9.1

Comment: Are they in iCloud? check on the website via a computer. Thumbnails should not be removed. Only quality is downgraded. Please check the number of photos at the end of the moments tab in photos app. https://www.imyfone.com/ios-data-recovery/photos-missing-from-icloud-photo-library/

Comment: no icloud sync is off and has always been. i think this somehow is correlated with free space but no there's LOT OF FREE SPACE. where're my photos??

Comment: Please post the version of your iPhone so we can see what the hardware spec is in relation to RAM-

Answer (score -1):

To free space in iPhotos ("*Camera Roll*"), on your iPhone (or iPad) go to:

***Albums*** > ***Recently Deleted*** and then select the photos for permanent deletion.  I'll bet you have tons of photos there gobbing up space.  That should take a lot of pressure off on your available space for photos.  Myself, well I didn't know that was there for ages ... ;-)

**Update**: After further details from the OP, sounds like he **CAN** take pictures and they are stored on the device, but these pics are just not appearing in "Camera Roll".  I suspect "Camera Roll" is an alias to the DCIM storage location.  Could be something wrong with how the thumbnails linking to the DCIM storage folder you reference are added.  Thus, the advice you were receiving on removing the SQL-lite db.

***Camera Roll*** itself must be an alias to that DCIM folder.  It would make no logical sense to have pictures stored in BOTH the DCIM folder and also ***Camera Roll***.  How these things interact would appear to be where the problem exists.

I remember with Outlook .pst folders there was a (2) GB limit (I believe) that buggered everything once the file hit 2GB.  I just checked this for you and the max SQL Lite file size is 140 TB, so this can't be the problem.  ***HOWEVER***, the size of the query as to what's retrievable in memory from a huge SQL Lite DB **CAN** be a limiting factor:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451624/will-sqlite-performance-degrade-if-the-database-size-is-greater-than-2-gigabytes

The upper limit as to the SQL query to the SQL Lite DB required to display the pics in "Camera Roll" looks a likely candidate if your pictures store is huge and the query size required to display them in Camera Roll is limited in memory

Comment: this folder is emply. my photos are missing in camera roll and moments but i can find them in DCIM folder. i don't know why iOS doesnt sync all that files ((( after removing **photos.sqlite**

Comment: Hmmm, that's probably not a space issue but a different sort of a problem.  So the photos aren't "missing" per se, but just not appearing in Camera Roll!  If the camera is taking pictures and they are being stored on the device, then the problem really is something to do with how those pics end-up in camera roll sounds a more accurate description of your problem.  Does that sound more like what you're experiencing?

Comment: on the other forum i found a solution that iOS may not show old photos to save some space. they advised to free up some space and reboot the phone and that should've done the drick but it didn't. that's why i was digging with **photos.sqlite** and so on. the problem is that the photos cannot SOMEHOW be indexed by iOS in photos.sqlite but appear in **DCIM**. what can i do??

Comment: Read the update to my answer: looks like the indexing has to happen from an SQL query and this could be limited in memory from the link I referenced in the update.  That would all appear to approximate the shape of your problem

Comment: that didn't help me at all. now i got stuck at a point when even deleting all those sqlite bases doesn't force ios to reindex photos - luckily i backed up all files before doing so. still i don't have my **HALF (5000)** of my library and no one gave me even a hint how to do it.

Comment: I never told you to delete anything!  I said folks telling you to delete the sql lite db suspected that your prob wasn't a storage but something on the SQL Lite side.  The link I gave you indeed suggests insufficient memory (RAM) to query a big sql lite db being a problem. All the photos are on the device so it's not a disk space issue, or one with pictures being "deleted"- they just don't appear in your Camera Roll, which is not itself a photo store but an alias to it.  These facts suggest it's an SQL Lite issue and the link I gave says SQL Lite queries might not complete with too little mem.

Comment: it's definitely on the sql side but nothing is working now, i can't even get back to restoring anything - i just put a backed up sql database and that's it. i tried to do the same this with another iphone (ios 8.1.4, about 9600 photos), deleted **photos.sqlite** and nothing got back  - i can't seem to find how to force iOS to reindex everything (or do it manually). well, NOTHING WORKS. the only reasonable but super time consuming idea is to copy everything to pc and then airdrop (hope it will be sorted correctly) but i'll lose my albums.

Comment: Presently I see (2) issues: A) You deleted the SQL Lite DB, so that needs re-creating before iPhotos can be restored.  B) You Need a way to test the possibility your photo store is so big you have insufficient memory to query it per the link in my answer. I found a new link for repairing a duff iPhotos library. Although it requires a Mac, if you can fix your iPhotos library on that, it tells you your photos CAN be displayed in iPhotos, but just not on your iPhone.  This would strongly suggest the issue is resourced-based, ie: not have enough RAM):  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204967

Comment: Just occurred to me you're using IOS 8: Apple is up to v 12.3.1 now.  I suspect you're using a much lower-spec hardware iPhone and a really outdated OS on it.  This leads me to believe even more strongly your iPhone doesn't have sufficient horsepower to deal with that mountain of pics you're trying to display.

Comment: 1. Generally speaking I had a similar problem when upgrading to a new version of iOS, at first all my photos were lost, but later iOS started restoring them all, and the number was much larger that 5000 - so I don't think  it's a matter of RAM. 2. Yesterday when I was ABLE to delete sql-base and forece autorestore feature it somehow started with a photo taken 4 years ago, not 5-6 but 4 years ago. How does it correlate with query?? I thought it should start just from the beginning - **100apple** folder. There's definitely something different (((